# What is the meaning of navigator in the song by The Pogues

Tags: meaning-in-context

The full text of the song can be found at:
http://www.pogues.com/Releases/Lyrics/LPs/RumSodomy/Navigator.html

Comment: LMGTFY. Heavy laborers.

Comment: See also [navvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navvy)

Comment: Originally building workers constructing canals (inland navigation) and then railways and then more generally.

Comment: Would it have cost too much effort to copy and pasted the line or verse where the word "navigator" appeared?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/navigator 5

Answer (score 1):

The labourers who dug out the canals in 18th century Britain were called 'navigators' or 'navvies'. 'Navigation' was an early term for a canal, different from the usual meaning of 'directing a ship' - there are many British pubs near canals or former canals called 'The Navigation Inn'.

Later, the term was used for railway or road construction workers, before the advent of mechanical digging machines.